# Write a string matrix on a .txt file on Python

Tags: python, json, string, matrix, roguelike

I'm doing a RogueLike game with Python and I use a DungeonGenerator.py. 
In my game I read the dungeons from a .txt file.

The problem is I can't write the dungeon I make with the DungeonGenerator.py on a .txt file because is a matrix of strings.

This is an example of the result of DungeonGenerator.py:

[Dungeon example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHn3b.png)

I try with:

```
return tiles
file = open ("Dungeon.txt", "w")
file.write(tiles)
file.close()
```

Obiously tiles isn't a string.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is called object serialization.

The [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) should work just fine for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..but it doesn't work to me because the data in the .txt is not like I need to read late with my main program.